# Finding the derivative of $\frac {\sqrt{x-1}}{3x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I am working through a textbook problem that requires me to find the derivative of $\frac {\sqrt{x-1}}{3x^2}$. I start by using the quotient rule and then simplifying.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{3x^2 \times \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-1/2}-(x-1)^{1/2} \times 6x}{9x^4}$$

From there:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{3x^2}{2(x-1)^{1/2}\times 9x^4} - \frac{(x-1)^{1/2} \times 6x}{9x^4}$$

Eventually I end up with:

$$\frac{2(x-1)}{x(x-1)^{1/2}}$$

But the textbook answer is $\frac{(x-1)^{-1/2} \times (-3x + 4)}{6x^3}$

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer of your book is wrong, or you wrongly copied it: $(x-1)^{1/2}$ should be in the denominator.

Comment: Yes. Stupidly didn't copy over properly. My answer is still incorrect though, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Factor out constants:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{3x^2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x^2}\right)$$

2. Use the procut rule $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(uv)=v\cdot\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}+u\cdot\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}$:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x^2}\right)=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)}{x^2}+\sqrt{x-1}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

3. Use the chain rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left((x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-1\right)}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$$

4. Differentiate the sum term by term:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-1\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(1\right)=1-0=1$$

5. Use the power rule $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^n\right)=nx^{n-1}$:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{-2}\right)=-2x^{-2-1}=-\frac{2}{x^3}$$

So, combining everything:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{3x^2}\right)=\frac{4-3x}{6x^3\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Comment: Yes. I see where I made my mistake. I changed the subtraction to multiplication. I rectified this and got the correct answer. Thank you for your help and the detailed explanation

Comment: @user183974 You're welcome I'm glad that I could help. Yes you've to be very carefull when are doing derivaive stuff

Answer (score 2):

First line should be
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{3x^2 \times \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-1/2}-
   (x-1)^{\color{red}{\Large +}1/2} \times 6x}{9x^4}$$

Because $\sqrt{x-1} = (x-1)^{1/2} \neq (x-1)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected. Made a mistake when typing in. Still I got my answer with positive exponent for the second term. Can you see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As JnxF points out, there is a typo in your first displayed expression, but your "From there" expression corrects it and is correct.  After that, though, you should get

$${dy\over dx}={3x^2-2(x-1)\times6x\over2(x-1)^{1/2}\times9x^4}={3x^2-12x(x-1)\over18x^4(x-1)^{1/2}}={12x-9x^2\over18x^4(x-1)^{1/2}}={4-3x\over6x^3(x-1)^{1/2}}$$